# I am trying to load images in angular from mysql database using nodejs but the chrome not allow to load local resource

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular

Here is the code of get request in nodejs
'''

```
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'D:/Angular/project/src/assets/image/')));

app.get('/newsform', (req, res) => {
  const qr = `SELECT id, headline, news, path, expirydate FROM newsform`;

  db.query(qr, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err, err);
    }

    if (result.length > 0) {
      res.send({
        message: 'all user data',
        data: result
      });
    }
  });
});
```

'''
Here is my angular ts file
'''

```
getAllData() {
    this.service.Newsformget().subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res, 'res');
      this.readData = res.data.map((us: any) => {
        // Update the path to use the new folder structure and replace the localhost with the correct IP address or domain name
        us.path = `assets/image/${us.path.split('/').pop()}`;

        return us;
      });
    });
  }
```

'''
here the problem is chrome not load local resource.
Help me to correct the code that chrome load images.

Comment: You are appending the `__dirname`, which is the absolute path to the project directory, to an absolute path, which should not be correct. Try `express.static('D:/Angular/project/src/assets/image/')` instead.

Comment: No bro its not working any other idea?

Comment: What error are you getting? Have you tried another path, like `path.join(__dirname, 'src/assets/image/')`?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) error is this it dont load the local resource